# Number Of Stars in 2D and 3D?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]
Though the picture is self explanatory and it is fairly easy to count the number of stars , how can I tackle this problem combinatorially? Any hint?

Comment: Is this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_stellated_dodecahedron ?

Comment: Are you asking to count in 3D or in 2D?

Comment: It would be interesting to take both the cases

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown : visually it can be taken both as a stellated dodecahedron or not one. The result may vary in both the cases.

Comment: I thought I knew what a “star” (polygon or polytope) is, but wouldn’t the above count as a single star? Or are you asking to count how many faces it has, each of which appear to be star polygons?

Comment: I am interested in all those figures which have five vertices and appear as stars , if you notice a star appears in the inside of a "pentagon" as well which need not be a "face" in 2D but only a part of the face . I hope I am able to explain even though the description maybe crude.